# I make log with CorrelationId in Serilog for email notification and tracking pixel in ASP.NET Core 6 Web API

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, correlation, appsettings, email-notifications, tracking-pixel

I make log with `CorrelationId` in Serilog for email service sender and tracking pixel in asp.net core 6 web api , each message log with GUID `correlationId` and when user see the message we can also log the time he opens the email message but problem is I want to make same `correlationId` log for both email message and the time user see the message but each action in this app make their own correlationID.

I think the problem is in middleware correlation and `program.cs`. Does anyone know how I could do that? Or is it even possible?

Thanks in advance.

The class for send email and send pixel tracking

```
using MailKit.Net.Smtp;
using MailKit.Security;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using MimeKit;
using MimeKit.Text;
using DAL.Model;
using ImageTracker.Service;

namespace SimpleEmailApp.Services
{
    public class MailService : IMailService
    {
        private readonly AppSetting _mailSetting;
        private readonly ILogger<MailService> _logger;
        private readonly IWhichMessageIsRead _whichMessageIsRead;

        // IWhichMessageIsRead whichMessageIsRead
        public MailService(IOptions<AppSetting> mailSetting, ILogger<MailService> logger,
                           IWhichMessageIsRead whichMessageIsRead)
        {
            _mailSetting = mailSetting.Value;
            _logger = logger;
            _whichMessageIsRead = whichMessageIsRead;
        }

        public async Task SendEmailAsync(EmailMessage message)
        {
            var email = new MimeMessage();

            try
            {
                email.Sender = MailboxAddress.Parse(_mailSetting.Mail);
                email.To.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(messsage.Reciver));

                email.Subject = messsage.Subject;

                // a unique-id to attach with the mail
                //  var messageId = Guid.NewGuid();

                //  bool IsRead = false;

                // the server that receives the request from the image and process it
                //  var deliveryProcessor = "https://localhost:7156/api/Track";

                // constructing the image tag with "src" pointing to the external resource
                // passing the unique-id in the query-string.

                var imgTag = string.Format(@"<img src=""https://localhost:7156/api/Mail"" alt ="""" width = ""1"" height = ""1"" 
                                style=""width: 0px; height: 0px; border:0px;""/>");

                var builder = new BodyBuilder();
                builder.HtmlBody = imgTag;

                email.Body = new TextPart(TextFormat.Html)
                {
                    Text =  message.Body + "         " +  imgTag 
                };

                var lg = _logger.LogInformation("");

               _logger.LogInformation("Email {@mailRequest} creates for {Sender} at {now}.", message, _mailSetting.Mail, DateTime.Now);
               
               _whichMessageIsRead. GetMessage(  ,messsage);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                _logger.LogError("Email is not sent.");
                throw;
            }

            using var smtp = new SmtpClient();

            try
            {
                smtp.Connect(_mailSetting.Host, _mailSetting.Port, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
                smtp.Authenticate(_mailSetting.Mail, _mailSetting.Password);
                await smtp.SendAsync(email);
                smtp.Disconnect(true);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                _logger.LogError(" SMTP Server Configuration Error occurred ");
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My middleware for implementing `correlationid`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace CorrelationProvider.Middleware
{
    public class LogHeaderMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public LogHeaderMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            var header = context.Request.Headers["X-SessionId"];

            if (header.Count > 0)
            {
                var logger = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ILogger<LogHeaderMiddleware>>();
                using (logger.BeginScope("{@SessionId}", header[0]))
                {
                    await _next(context);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                await _next(context);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`program.cs`:

```
global using SimpleEmailApp.Services;
using DAL.Model;
using SimpleEmailApp.ConfgureSetting;
using Serilog;
using CorrelationProvider.Middleware;
using CorrelationProvider;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
//using ImageTracker.Middleware;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddControllers();

//builder.Host.UseSerilog();
var Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
     .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration)
      .Enrich.FromLogContext()
     .Enrich.WithCorrelationId()
     .CreateLogger();
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddSerilog(Logger);

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

/// <summary>
/// correlation provider
/// </summary>
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ISessionIdAccessor, SessionIdAccessor>();
/// <summary>
/// /below confiure method is add appsettings.development.json values to  appsettings.json and 
/// configure host(smtp server settings) for us .
/// also congigure method is made by mailsetting c# class properties and fill with mailsetting in 
/// appsettings.development.json file 
/// we can use appsettings.json instead appsettings.development.json .
/// </summary>
//builder.Services.Configure<AppSetting>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MailSetting"));

builder.Services.Configure<AppSetting>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MailSetting"));

builder.Services.ConfigureWritable<AppSetting>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MailSetting"));

//builder.Services.AddSingleton<FileContentResult>(new FileContentResult(

//                   Convert.FromBase64String(builder.Configuration.GetValue<String>("Response:PixelContentBase64")),

//                   builder.Configuration.GetValue<String>("Response:PixelContentType")
//      ));


builder.Host.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
{
    config.AddJsonFile("MailSetting",
                       optional: true,
                       reloadOnChange: true);
});

builder.Services.AddScoped<IMailService, MailService>();

/// <summary>
/// correlation Id
/// </summary>

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseMiddleware<LogHeaderMiddleware>();

//app.UseMiddleware<EmailTrackMiddleware>();

/// <summary>
/// static files for sending 1x1 pic 
/// </summary>
//app.UseDefaultFiles();
//app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

My `appsettings.json` file:

```
{
  "MailSetting": {
    "Mail": "michelminestein@gmail.com",
    "Password": "quafcvofqjwfvhqu",
    "Host": "smtp.gmail.com",
    "Port": 587
  },
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [
      "Serilog.Sinks.File",
      "Serilog.Sinks.Console"
    ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "SimpleEmailApp.Controllers": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Information",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "Args": {
          "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz}  {Level:u11}] {CorrelationId}  {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}",
          "theme": "Serilog.Sinks.SystemConsole.Themes.AnsiConsoleTheme::Code, Serilog.Sinks.Console",
          "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Compact.RenderedCompactJsonFormatter, Serilog.Formatting.Compact"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "../logs/EmailApi-.log",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} {Level:u11}] {CorrelationId} {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Any solution to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

One possible I forgot to mention is in message model I can add message ID and GUID in it, with this solution we can track which message is read by client

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).